# add/remove c# event handlers with a single method

Tags: c#, events, delegates, operators, eventhandler

Is there a way to add  and remove event handlers in c# by passing the operators += and -= as arguments, so a single method could do it?

I am trying to avoid the repetitive:

```
AttachHandlers()
{
   event1 += handler1;
   event2 += handler2;
   // etc...
}

DetachHandlers()
{
   event1 -= handler1;
   event2 -= handler2;
   // etc...
}
```

or

```
AttachDetachHandlers(bool attach)
{
   if (attach)
   {
     event1 += handler1;
     event2 += handler2;
   // etc...
   }
   else
   {
     event1 -= handler1;
     event2 -= handler2;
   }
}
```

Instead, I would like to write something like this:

```
AttachDetachHandlers(operator addRemove)
{
  addRemove(event1, handler1);
  addRemove(event2, handler2);
  // etc...
}
```

being used with something like:

```
AttachDetachHandlers(+=);
```

Ideally it should work with event & handlers having different signatures (just like += & -= do).

Comment: Why not just use an if statement based on a boolean?

Comment: @Juan: because it is still just as repetitive (added an example to the question)

Comment: @Sinatr I don't want to detach handlers immediately after attaching them. I want a single function to replace AttachHandlers() and DetachHandlers()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    public static void Attach<T>(ref EventHandler<T> a, EventHandler<T> b)
    {
        a += b;
    }

    public static void Detach<T>(ref EventHandler<T> a, EventHandler<T> b)
    {
        a -= b;
    }

    public static void AttachDetachHandlers<T>(Action<ref EventHandler<T>, EventHandler<T>> op)
    {
        op(ref event1, handler1);
        op(ref event2, handler2);
        //etc...
    }
```

Then use like this:

```
        AttachDetachHandlers<int>(Attach);
        //...
        AttachDetachHandlers<int>(Detach);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this sample code. But notice that the signature of event handlers must be the same.

```
class Program
{
    delegate void dlgHandlerOperation<T>(ref EventHandler<T> Event, EventHandler<T> Handler);

    static void SetHandler<T>(ref EventHandler<T> Event, EventHandler<T> Handler) { Event += Handler; }
    static void UnsetHandler<T>(ref EventHandler<T> Event, EventHandler<T> Handler) { Event -= Handler; }

    static void SetAll(dlgHandlerOperation<int> Op)
    {
        Op(ref ev, foo);
        Op(ref ev, bar);
    }

    static event EventHandler<int> ev;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetAll(SetHandler);
        ev?.Invoke(null, 5);

        SetAll(UnsetHandler);
        ev?.Invoke(null, 6);
    }

    static void foo(object sender, int e) { Console.WriteLine("foo => " + e); }
    static void bar(object sender, int e) { Console.WriteLine("bar => " + e); }
}
```